# CentOS sssd: How to allow specific AD security group with space in the name to login while deny everything else?

Tags: linux, centos, active-directory, sssd

People,

In CentOS v8 sssd: How to allow specific AD security group with space in the name to log in while denying everything else?

The AD security group is **Domain Admins**

I have tested the id but nothing is working:

```
[root@PRDLINUX01-VM ~]# id -g Domain Admins@domain.com
id: extra operand ‘Admins@domain.com’
Try 'id --help' for more information.

[root@PRDLINUX01-VM ~]# id -g 'Domain Admins@domain.com'
id: ‘Domain Admins@domain.com’: no such user

[root@PRDLINUX01-VM ~]# id -g "Domain Admins@domain.com"
id: ‘Domain Admins@domain.com’: no such user

[root@PRDLINUX01-VM ~]# id -g 'Domain Admins'@domain.com
id: ‘Domain Admins@domain.com’: no such user

[root@PRDLINUX01-VM ~]# id -g "Domain Admins"@domain.com
id: ‘Domain Admins@domain.com’: no such user
```

This is the **/etc/sssd/sssd.conf** content:

```
[sssd]
domains = DOMAIN.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/DOMAIN.com]
ad_domain = DOMAIN.com
krb5_realm = DOMAIN.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ldap
ldap_access_filter = (memberOf=CN=Domain Admins,CN=Groups,DC=DOMAIN,dc=com)
```

I can only type in the username in Putty as Myself.Admin@DOMAIN.com, but then if the password is correct, I get:

```
---------------------------
PuTTY Fatal Error
---------------------------
Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Strangely the system can validate the password against AD, if it is false, it will re-prompt me for the correct password.
If it is correct, then the connection is closed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no user named `Domain Admins` and that it is a group. What are you actually trying to do? `id -g` is not a useful demonstration of anything here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I've updated the config file as above.

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: You are a Senior Systems Engineer but who is managing infrastructure but you don't know to check logs???

Comment: cat: /var/log/secure: No such file or directory
cat: /var/log/messages: No such file or directory

Comment: Then they would be in the journal (and you should turn rsyslog back on, or arrange for the journal to be shipped somewhere else, if you want more persistent logs).